# Error in PowerBI DAX comparsion operations do not support comparing values of type text with values of type integer

Tags: powerbi, dax

IF (Calender[income]<7000,"Silvercard", IF (Calender[income]<90000,"Goldcard","NoCard")) Can u give solution to this?? Can anyone tell me the error.

Shows above error in POWERBI i.e. DAX comparsion operations do not support comparing values of type text with values of type integer

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the data type of your column `Calender[income]`.
It is best practice to change the column data type to `whole number` or `decimal`.

Also, what you can do but is not ideal is using `VALUE` to transform the text into a number.

```
CalculatedColumn =
IF (
    VALUE ( Calender[income] ) < 7000,
    "Silvercard",
    IF ( VALUE ( Calender[income] ) < 90000, "Goldcard", "NoCard" )
)
```

Comment: Target customer = IF(Customer [gender]="M" &&  Customer[income]>120000 &&  Customer[total child]>3, "YES","NO")                               For this also i applied same but shows error....solution pls...Shows above error.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your data types. As point out in my answer you need to change them before import. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/data-types

Comment: SYNTAx is incorrect for sales...........sumx = SUMX(RELATEDTABLE (sales),sales[REVNUE])